# Custom Rig doesn't show

Tags: rigging, bones

I created a skeleton from scratch and clicked on *generate rig* but the rig appears empty, just the arrows, there is a "hidden" rig in another layer but I can only move it, scale it and rotate it, it isn't a "real rig"
PD: I have riggify activated

Comment: Did you start from  a meta-rig?  Did you select the "arrows" and went to pose mode? Please add a screenshot of the rig.

Comment: In order for Rigify to work, in needs bones structured in certain ways with certain additional meta data. Unless you start with the meta rig, or use the various rigify function to add rig parts, then you wont have this information.